# Get all forms from $scope

Tags: angularjs

1. Is it possible to get all the forms from the $scope and set them to prestine?
   Up to now I have been setting the prestine state using the form name, e.g.

   `$scope.coachingSessionFrm.$setPristine()`
2. the `setPrestine()` method removes the dirty flag so that the state of the form elements are now considered `clean` right? Only after a change after `prestine` will they be dirty?

Comment: 1. Not as far as I know, you can make an array of form names and loop through them or something if you have a lot of forms and want cleaner code. 2. Correct.